# Trigger Cucumber BDD tests within an android app when I click a button from the app

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, automated-tests, cucumber

I have an app built for testing to trigger tests from within the app its for a specific use case can't be done other way. I need to run the tests using BDD.

This app calls some api from a library thats added as a dependency to the app. Now I have some '.feature' files that has test cases for those api's I have to trigger these tests from the app when I click a button in the app.

I cannot launch the tests as new activity...it needs to run in the existing activity I cannot place the test steps and features in the test package...I need to keep it in the in main.

I tried using the android-cucumber library....I was able to parse the feature file from external storage of the app....but its unable to map the stepdefinitions.

The loadBackends() method from cucumber returns empty/null. The problem I think is that the cucumber cannot glue/find the step def in the app.

I have the step def class in same package as the app's other classes

is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?....if so how?